# Pushing to GitHub 403 error permission denied

Tags: git, github, repository, push

Trying to push a file and getting this error:

```
remote: Permission to AndrewPreciado/CS6432016.git denied to Adrew64.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/AndrewPreciado/CS6432016.git/':
The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Adrew64 refers to my an old github account username I used back in the day, but I want to use this new account with AndrewPreciado.

Anything I can do?  Thanks

Comment: Just follow this instructions and add Adrew64 as a collaborator: https://help.github.com/articles/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository/

Comment: Thank you very very much! That did the trick.

Comment: I knew it!... I am glad to help :)

Comment: yeah add collaborator also works for me:)

Answer (score 3):

Your computer has saved local credentials

Follow the following steps on windows:
open control panel -> user accounts -> manage your credentials -> window credentials -> delete git account credentials

It will work fine then.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way to delete the stored credetials for old user is

```
git credential-osxkeychain erase
```

then on the next line type these

```
 host=github.com
 protocol=https
<press return or enter key>
```

then try pushing the code again it will ask you for credentials username & password and then this should work